# Rails 6 Zeitwerk "DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants..." but I can't figure out where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

I swear I've read the docs and I think I have a basic understanding of the principles, but I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm loading these constants inappropriately.

I'm working to upgrade an app that was originally Rails 5.2

I'm getting this warning when I run RSpec, a server, a local console, etc.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants ApplicationHelper, EventsHelper, FontAwesome::Rails::IconHelper, DeviseHelper, ErrorHandler, and ApplicationController.

Being able to do this is deprecated. Autoloading during initialization is going
to be an error condition in future versions of Rails.
```

Here are the constants that are being inappropriately autoloaded:

- ApplicationHelper - standard Rails file
- EventsHelper - *standard Rails file for EventsController*
- FontAwesome::Rails::IconHelper - *from a gem, not in my app directory*
- DeviseHelper - *from a gem, not in my app directory*
- ErrorHandler - *Located at 'app/controllers/concerns/error_handler'*
- ApplicationController - *standard Rails file*

I've looked for instances where I might be calling `include` or `require` for these constants, but found none. I especially focused on my initializers.

I've run (and read through) `bin/rails zeitwerk:check` without any obvious hints. I see these instances getting loaded as expected:

```
...
Zeitwerk@rails.main: constant ApplicationHelper loaded from file /Users/ckragt/ruby/filterbuildscheduler/app/helpers/application_helper.rb
...
Zeitwerk@rails.main: constant EventsHelper loaded from file /Users/ckragt/ruby/filterbuildscheduler/app/helpers/events_helper.rb
...
Zeitwerk@rails.main: constant FontAwesome::Rails::IconHelper loaded from file /Users/ckragt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.7/app/helpers/font_awesome/rails/icon_helper.rb
...
Zeitwerk@rails.main: constant DeviseHelper loaded from file /Users/ckragt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb
...
Zeitwerk@rails.main: constant ErrorHandler loaded from file /Users/ckragt/ruby/filterbuildscheduler/app/controllers/concerns/error_handler.rb
...
Zeitwerk@rails.main: autoload set for ApplicationController, to be loaded from /Users/ckragt/ruby/filterbuildscheduler/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
```

I am using Spring and Binstub (both updated to latest versions).

Here's the top of my `application.rb` file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require_relative 'boot'
require 'csv'

require 'rails'
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require 'active_model/railtie'
require 'active_job/railtie'
require 'active_record/railtie'
# require "active_storage/engine"
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'action_mailer/railtie'
# require 'action_mailbox/engine'
# require 'action_text/engine'
require 'action_view/railtie'
# require 'action_cable/engine'
require 'sprockets/railtie'
# require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'

require 'google/apis/gmail_v1'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module BuildPlanner
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0
...
```

**Any ideas of where else I should look?**

Comment: Hey, the problem is that your initialization code is loading reloadable classes and modules. This is conceptually broken (because on reload whatever happened during boot used now gone and obsolete objects), and it is just not possible to do that anymore in Rails 7. Have you seen this section of the guide? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-when-the-application-boots

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out this seems to be related to `rails_admin`.

### How I learned this:

[Someone else](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/initialization-autoloaded-the-constants-x-y-and-z-isnt-enough-information) shared my frustration at the warning message and asked for more help tracing the issue.

[One response](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/initialization-autoloaded-the-constants-x-y-and-z-isnt-enough-information/74719/6) recommended putting `pp caller_locations` at the top of one of the files that was being autoloaded. Doing this gave me a traceback I could use. That's when I noticed that `rails_admin` appeared as a path in each one.

I noticed I already had a huge list of `require` statements in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`:

```
require 'money-rails/rails_admin'
require 'rails_admin/adapters/active_record'
require 'application_record'
require 'user'
require 'event'
require 'registration'
require 'location'
require 'technology'
require 'supplier'
require 'component'
require 'part'
require 'material'
require 'count'
require 'inventory'
require 'extrapolate_component_part'
require 'extrapolate_material_part'
require 'extrapolate_technology_component'
require 'extrapolate_technology_part'
require 'extrapolate_technology_material'
```

For a lark, I commented all of them out, then ran a RSpec test. My warning message suddenly got SUPER long with a bunch more instances:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants ApplicationHelper, EventsHelper, FontAwesome::Rails::IconHelper, DeviseHelper, ErrorHandler, ApplicationController, ApplicationRecord, User, Event, Registration, Location, Technology, Component, Part, Material, Supplier, Count, Inventory, ExtrapolateComponentPart, ExtrapolateMaterialPart, ExtrapolateTechnologyComponent, ExtrapolateTechnologyPart, and ExtrapolateTechnologyMaterial.
```

So I decided to add in my previous instances:

```
require 'application_helper'
require 'events_helper'
require 'devise_helper'
require 'error_handler'
require 'application_controller'
```

...to my already long list, my warning message, all of them but the `FontAwesome::Rails::IconHelper` goes away. I think I can get that one too, if I can just figure out the correct filepath.

Comment: The trace finally helped me to get rid of the deprecation warning. Just had to find the initial calls from the initializers and wrap them in `Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do . . . end`

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but I found this to be helpful. Say you are encountering..

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants Thing
```

All you need is to go to where its getting defined, and cause a compiler error:

```rb
# some/thing.rb

foo # blow up the initialization
class Thing
  ...
end
```

You should now be able to find where it is getting required.

Comment: Good strategy! Could probably also debug at that point and see where you are in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by gem `recaptcha` and `wicked_pdf`.

Updated these gems to the latest versions fixes the problem.

- Link to the [recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha)
- Link to the [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)

Hope it will save someones time.